# Apache Webserver Redirect

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

A very basic question I'm sure, don't seem to be able to find solution online.

I have an Apache Webserver (Apache/2.4.6) with a Virtual Host Configuration.

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/content/folder

<Directory /path/to/content/>
                    RewriteEngine On
                    Order deny,allow
                    Require all granted
                    RewriteRule "^/p1$" "/p1/"
</Directory>
```

I have a .htaccess file sitting in /p1/ which returns a html file with a javascript redirect embedded (not my choice, code has been handed to me).

I'm trying to configure this in such a way as to redirect any incoming request with a /p1 to the /p1/ folder to then be redirected by the default .html file sitting inside.

Is this possible to do without turning DirectorySlash Off, or an Alias? i.e. is it possible to have a rewrite rule to do this?

Comment: What I’m getting from this is that you’re trying to redirect a request to /p1/ to the folder /p1/. Isn’t that where it would go by default? Or are you saying you have URLs where the placement of `p1` varies?

Comment: Sorry if not clear, trying to map a URL ending in "/p1" to redirect to folder "/p1/" - with the end result being if I type <URL>/p1 I don't get a timeout and instead get a redirect to <URL>/p1/ (which is a folder).

Comment: Please include examples of the URLs.

Comment: Okay: if I have a URL dns1.dev.net.au and I try to navigate to dns1.dev.net.au/p1/ works fine, would like dns1.dev.net.au/p1 to also resolve. Document Root is: /path/to/content/folder, and p1 folder is at /path/to/content/folder/p1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a trailing slash optional use this:

```
RewriteRule "^p1\/?$" "/p1/"
```

`^` and `$` are our anchors.

`\/` matches a single forward slash (the backslash is an escape character).

`?` makes the previous match optional.

So we've made the trailing slash of a URL optional with `\/?`

You could also try something lie this:

```
RewriteRule "^(.+)\/?$" "/$1/"
```

`(.+)` matches everything and then we add the optional trailing slash `(.+)\/?`

`/$1/` rewrites to what was matched in the parentheses.

So the URL `/foo/bar` would redirect to `foo/bar/`

And `/bar/foo` redirects to `/bar/foo/`

The redirect is now dynamic.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) is a decent intro to regex.

[This](http://regexr.com/) is also a good reference and utility for working out regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both, but I don't seem to be getting a rewrite happening. I've confirmed Rewrite module is enabled etc. Will give it +1 as I'm sure this is correct answer. Must be something to do with this setup (could be because sitting behind an ELB). Best I can get is a 301 redirect from /p1 to /p1/.